# Stop AWS lambda event source from pushing events if downstream service is down

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, fifo, aws-sam

Is there a way to dynamically stop consuming events, when using aws lambda's built-in event source mapping? In the example diagram I would rely on the Big Service's healthceck to make that decision.

So far I know that if Big Service is down, I could retry processing and eventually put the message in a DLQ. I would prefer to keep the messages in the original queue and thus preserve their order without having to manage processing from DLQ and the FIFO when Big Survice is back.

[image: The red X signifies a failing healthcheck]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this via Lambda's [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html#configuration-concurrency-reserved).

As stated in the docs:

> To throttle a function, set the reserved concurrency to zero. This stops any events from being processed until you remove the limit.

Lambda SDK has a handy method to set the concurrency.

```
putFunctionConcurrency(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request
```

And when the downstream service is back, I could delete that setting and resume at the previous pace:

```
 deleteFunctionConcurrency(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request
```

My design now is to have a second lambda function monitoring the downstream service's health. When downstream is down, I will set the reserved concurrency to 0, and when it is back up, I will delete the concurrency setting. I am still thinking if I can make the function trigger on a cloudwatch event or trigger it on a time interval, but that is a different question.

Comment: I am going forward with this solution, as the config of concurrency seems easier to achieve. There is less information required in the payload. I will take the EventBridge idea from Ersoy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this but one option could be;

- create another lambda to make health check requests to `big service`
- create an [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/run-lambda-schedule.html) rule to trigger health check lambda [periodically](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/scheduled-events.html)(1 minute)
- if the service is down use [UpdateEventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateEventSourceMapping.html#API_UpdateEventSourceMapping_RequestSyntax)'s `Enabled` option to disable the source mapping between lambda and sqs.
- When the service is up again, use `UpdateEventSourceMapping` again to enable the mapping between sqs and lambda.

One of the drawback is that;

> EventBridge does not provide second-level precision in schedule expressions. The finest resolution using a cron expression is a minute.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to temporarily/dynamically stop Lambda consuming the vents.

The only option would be to **remove the trigger** to prevent Lambda from being activated when messages arrive in the Amazon SQS queue.

Then, when things are okay again, add the trigger back. I haven't tried attaching a Lambda trigger where there are messages *already* in the queue, but hopefully the will be processed.